# How factually correct is the verse translation and order given in Osho's Book of secrets on Vijnana Bhairava Tantra to the original Sanskrit version?

Tags: shiva, tantra, shaivism, meditation, kashmiri-shaivism

**For any slow people, reading this quesiton, first of all this is not an opinion based question, it is a factual, scriptural based question. It is asking whether the order of the methods are same and if the given methods are same as original Sanskrit work. If you think this is an opinion based question please get educated. Objective reasonable translation and order of objective physical methods is not opinion based.** Read the question slowly and carefully.

---

Osho has translated(?) and delivered a set of lengthy discourses on Vijnana Bhairava Tantra which is compiled to a book called [Book of secrets](https://allbooksworld.com/the-book-of-secrets-by-osho-pdf-download/).

The famous, Swami Laxman Joo has also written two books on it called [Vijnana Bhairava: The practice of centering Awareness](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.gianfrancobertagni.it/materiali/tantra/joo2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjyxsuRt471AhU_SmwGHZ9FDu8QFnoECCEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0SX3iv-ZdtxjURpCjcqpRQ) and [Manual of Self Realisation](https://archive.org/details/the-manual-for-self-realization-112-meditations-of-the-vijnana-bhairava-tantra/mode/2up), where has has translated verse by verse.

There is yet another book [Sri Vijnana Bhairava Tantra The Ascent By Swami Satsangananda Saraswati](https://archive.org/details/SriVijnanaBhairavaTantraTheAscentSwamiSatsanganandaSaraswati), which translated word by word and then gives the total translation. This book seems to agree with Swami Laxman Joo's book.

Any one can easily see that verses have been translated quite faithfully and this is not opinion based. Now in Osho's book there is no original Sanskrit verse, it straight up gives English translation and then explains it. Now the methods, for first two or three seems to be the same but then on from the fifth method seems it to be completely different method. The methods agree with Swami Laxman Joo's book on and off. Did Osho rearrange the methods  or did he give totally new set of practices other than the classical ones by his own?

---

Book of Secrets by Osho, List of meditations

[image]

---

Compare this with the meditations offered  in the book translated by Swami Laxman Joo. Why are the Dharans or Meditations different?

Comment: Edit old question instead of posting new question

Comment: Moreover, this is an opinion based topic.

Comment: Oh, ok  i see. So the guy reposted his own closed topic question and then left the site. Huh. ..